# Bounding solutions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to prove the following lemma:

> Let $x'=f(x,t)$ be a ODE and consider a derivable function $y(t)$ such that $y'(t) < f(y(t), t)$. Then if for a certain solution $x$ of the ODE and a certain $t_0$ we have that $x(t_0) \ge y(t_0)$ then we always have that $x(t) > y(t)$ for all $t > t_0$

Intuitively this seems correct to me, but the formal proof eludes me.

Is this true? Is there a simple proof?

Comment: @AVK how would we know that f(x,t) > y'(t)? We only know that f(y,t) > y'(t)

Comment: You mean "a certain $t_0$ we have $x(t_0) \ge y(t_0)$", right?  Not $x(t_0) \ge y(t)$.

Comment: @RobertLewis That is right, I have edited the Q

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this matter.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $f(x, t)$ is jointly continuous in $x$ and $t$.  This is a pretty typical assumption for such $f(x, t)$ in the context of ordinary differential equations.

We observe that the above assumption implies that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are both continuous.  This follows from the fact that they are both differentiable, $x(t)$ because it satisfies

$x'(t) = f(x(t), t), \tag 1$

and $y(t)$ by hypothesis--it is given differentiable, and this implies continuity.

We are given that

$y(t_0) \le x(t_0) \tag 2$

and that

$y'(t) < f(y(t), t); \tag 3$

if now

$y(t_0) < x(t_0), \tag 4$

then by the continuity of $x(t)$, $y(t)$ we see that there is some $t_1  > t_0$ such that

$y(t) < x(t), \tag 5$

for $t \in [t_0, t_1]$.  In particular,

$y(t_1) < x(t_1); \tag 6$

if, on the other hand,

$y(t_0) = x(t_0), \tag 7$

then we may write

$x(t) - y(t) = (x(t_0) - y(t_0)) + \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t (x'(s) - y'(s)) ds = \int_{t_0}^t (x'(s) - y'(s)) ds; \tag 8$

now, at $t = t_0$ we have

$y'(t_0) < f(y(t_0), t_0) = f(x(t_0), t_0) = x'(t_0); \tag 9$

again by the continuity of $x'(t)$, $y'(t)$ we may select $t_1$ sufficiently small that

$x'(t) - y'(t) > 0, \; t \in [t_0, t_1], \tag{10}$

and this implies *via* (8) that

$x(t) - y(t) = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t (x'(s) - y'(s)) ds > 0, \tag{11}$

and hence

$y(t) < x(t) \; \text{for} \; t \in (0, t_1], \tag{12}$

whence in particular

$y(t_1) < x(t_1). \tag{13}$

We have now established that, under the given hypothesis, there is a $t_1 > t_0$ such that

$x(t) > y(t) \; t \in (t_0, t_1]. \tag{14}$

Next we assume that, for *some* $t > t_1$,

$y(t) = x(t); \tag{15}$

given that such $t$ exists, we let $\tau$ be the least $t$ satisfying (15).  By (14), $\tau > t_1$; since

$y(\tau) = x(\tau), \tag{16}$

we may affirm that

$y'(\tau) < f(y(\tau), \tau) = f(x(\tau), \tau) = x'(\tau); \tag{17}$

and again by continuity we may find some $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$y'(t) < x'(t) \; \text{for} \; t \in [\tau - \epsilon, \tau]. \tag{18}$

Noting that

$y(\tau - \epsilon) < x(\tau - \epsilon), \tag{19}$

we may apply (8), replacing $t_0$ with $\tau - \epsilon$ and $t$ with $\tau$:

$x(\tau) - y(\tau)$
$= (x(\tau - \epsilon) - y(\tau - \epsilon)) + \displaystyle \int_{\tau - \epsilon}^\tau (x'(s) - y'(s)) ds > x(\tau - \epsilon) - y(\tau - \epsilon) > 0 \tag{20}$

by virtue of (18), in contradiction to (16); thus no $\tau > t_1$ such that (16) binds exists.  We have thus shown that $x(t) > y(t)$ for all $t > t_0$.

Comment: Wonderful answer! One detail I am not sure I fully understand: how do we deduce (17) from (16)?

Comment: @Jsevillamol:  we are given that $y(t) < f(y(t), t)$ for all $t$.  Thus, for $t = \tau$, $y'(\tau) < f(y(\tau), \tau)$.  But since $y(\tau) = x(\tau)$, $f(y(\tau), \tau) = f(x(\tau), \tau) = x'(\tau)$, since $x(t)$ satisfies $x'(t) = f(x(t), t)$.  Hope this  clarifies.  Thanks for you kind words, and for you "acceptance",  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Let $t_*>t_0$ be the point of the first intersection of $y=y(t)$ and $x=x(t)$:
[image: the picture]

We have $x(t_*)=y(t_*)$;
$y(t)$ is below $x(t)$, thus, $\dot y(t_*)\ge \dot x(t_*)=f(x(t_*),t)=f(y(t_*),t)$. It contradicts with the condition $\dot y(t)<f(y(t),t)$, therefore, $y=y(t)$ and $x=x(t)$ do not intersect.

Comment: Nice graphic, how did you make/insert it into your post?

Comment: @Robert Lewis I used MS Paint :) and the image upload button on the top of the 'Your answer' dialog

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that in $t_0$ we have that x and y may coincide, and thus we have no information about the derivative. What happens in that case?

Comment: In this case we have $\dot y(t_0)<f(y(t_0),t_0)=f(x(t_0),t_0)=\dot x(t_0)$; since the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}(x-y)=\dot x(t)-\dot y(t)$ is continuous, its sign remains unchanged (positive) in some neighborhood $(t_0,t_0+\epsilon)$; thus, $x(t)-y(t)$ in this neighborhood is strictly increasing  and $x(t)-y(t)>0$.